# how to save data filled in pdf using ABCpdf or EOPdf in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a Pdf with input fields and i want to save the data filled in these field and the output should be a pdf i have searched on net but still notable to find helpful code... or any other example. Please help me as soon as possible. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

abcPDF is useful for this, you can get the data from the PDF using one of the examples in their help file. You can use the same tool to read out the form fields and then write them back into another copy of the document.

Alternatively you can probably use the Stamp() method they provide to lock the fields into the document and save it.

You can try abcPDF for free for 30 days.